# Javascript dialog() function is not working in my MVC code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

Here my JS code

```
      $(function () {

               $(".button").live("click", function () {
        alert("Dialog page function is working!");
        $(".dialog").dialog("open");
    });

        $(".dialog").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
});



<td>
    <input type="button" value="Add Value" class="button" />
</td>
```

I have edit my code.. I have include the alertbox in side the button.. i am able to get the alert box when i click the button but dialog box is not wrking

Comment: please define 'not working', do you get any errors?

Comment: Do you have an element with `class="dialog"`?

Comment: no i didn get any error but when i click the button am not getting any popup page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have nested two `document.ready` functions. Try like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".button").live("click", function () {
        $(".dialog").dialog("open");
    });

    $(".dialog").dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: { 
            "Ok": function () { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            } 
        } 
    });
});
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/gnNjH/1/)

---

UPDATE:

After the numerous comments it looks like there are still problems with setting this up in an ASP.NET MVC application. So here's a step by step guide to get a working solution:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 2 application
2. Replace the contents of `Index.aspx` view with the following:

   ```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Index</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function () {
               $('.button').live('click', function () {
                   $('.dialog').dialog('open');
               });

               $('.dialog').dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   buttons: {
                       'Ok': function () {
                           $(this).dialog('close');
                       }
                   }
               });
           });
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <input type="button" value="Add Value" class="button" /> 
       <div class="dialog"> 
           sadffasdf
       </div> 
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Run the application
4. Click on the Add value button

Comment: Yes, i tried with this code.. but no luck.. im getting popup screen

Comment: @Dhana, are you getting a javascript error? Are the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts referenced? Also do you have a placeholder (`<div class="dialog"></div>`) somewhere on your page where the dialog should show?

Comment: Yes i had div like this <div class="dialog">javascript dialog page
</div>... i tried with the http://jsfiddle.net/Bgz5E/53/ but no luck.. please advice

Comment: @Dhana, in your example you didn't reference jQuery UI even if that was what I told you in my previous comment. I wrote a working example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/gnNjH/1/

Comment: Code is working fine.. i am really sorry to say this same code is not working with my MVC2.Please help

Comment: @Dhana, you are only asking question but not answering any of mine. You only say *it's not working* but this is a meaningless phrase to me. So I repeat my question once again: do you get any javascript error in the console? Have you properly included the jQuery UI script to your page?

Comment: i am sorry.. I am not getting any script error.. i am running my MVC code in Mozilla.. there i am unable to get the dialog popup..And one more the script u have given in the jsfiddle.net/gnNjH/1 is working fine but the same code is not working with my MVC code..

Comment: @Dhana, see my update. I have posted a full working example of how an ASP.NET MVC view could look like to get a jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: Thank you.. Your code is working fine.. Actually i got the script error when i was trying my old code..Error is like "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: I understand i missed lib files but after then i have added and include like this     <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.14.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> but even i am getting script as i mention above..